# How to check that a function is included only in pages of a subfolder

Tags: php, directory

I'd like some help please.

I have the structure of the site looks like this:

```
root folder(mysite):
- subfolder: includes (has inside the initialize.php - I include it on the top of ALL my pages )
- subfolder: admin (has inside the localhost/mysite/admin/index.php, localhost/mysite/admin/edit.php, localhost/mysite/admin/delete.php)

index.php(localhost/mysite/admin/index.php )
albums.php
```

I also have a function loggedin() that allows access to the pages inside admin folder only when the user is logged in. So the code inside the admin pages is like this:

```
<?php require_once('../includes/initialize.php'); ?>
<?php loggedin(); //I put this only in pages inside admin folder ?>
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
/// Instead inside root pages is like this:
<?php require_once('includes/initialize.php'); ?>
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
```

What I'd like to do though, is to put my function inside the initialize.php and also perform a check that makes sure loggedin() is included ONLY in all the pages that are inside the admin folder, so the localhost/mysite/index.php won't have it, instead localhost/mysite/admin/index.php will have it.

Comment: Note that the correct spelling is `initialize` not `initilize`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put something like this in the initilize.php file

```
$dir = basename(dirname(__FILE__));
if($dir == 'admin') {
    loggedIn();
}
```

That would be a really simple way of doing it and it would only work if the admin/ directory does not contain any other directories.

**EDIT**

```
$dir = basename(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```

Should give you the current directory you are in. So if you are on the *admin/index.php* page `$dir` will now be equal to `admin`. Do the little `if` statement to check if the directory is equal to admin and if it is do the login check.

Well now anything in the admin/ directory is going to call the loggedIn() function so you will have to place the login.php file outside of the admin/ directory or else do something like

```
$fileName = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
if($dir == 'admin' && $fileName != 'login.php') {
    loggedIn();
}
```

It will get the job done but I'd advise you to look into Access Control Lists.

Comment: `__FILE__` is the current file, so *initilize.php*. You're looking for `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`.

Comment: Oh yeah that's it I never tested it before I wrote it down.

Comment: yes I echoed __FILE__ and gives me the path to the initialize.php. What I really want, isn't the path to the pages inside admin folder??

Comment: I changed it to this $dir = basename(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])); and seems to working, the problem now is that is failing when doing a redirect. Is it possible that the login.php is inside my admin folder too??? (im not having the loggedIn() function inside login.php)

Comment: Updated the previous reply.